# is there a way to simplify multiple setTimeout functions?

Tags: javascript, settimeout, simplify

I have multiple setTimeout functions and its making my code look lazy and long. is there a way to simplify this?

```
window.setTimeout(function () {
  $('.b1, .t5').addClass('active');
}, 3000);
window.setTimeout(function () {
  $('.b1, .t5').removeClass('active');
}, 3200);

window.setTimeout(function () {
  $('.b2, .t4').addClass('active');
}, 3100);
window.setTimeout(function () {
  $('.b2, .t4').removeClass('active');
}, 3300);

window.setTimeout(function () {
  $('.b3, .t3').addClass('active');
}, 3200);
window.setTimeout(function () {
  $('.b3, .t3').removeClass('active');
}, 3400);

window.setTimeout(function () {
  $('.b4, .t2').addClass('active');
}, 3300);
window.setTimeout(function () {
  $('.b4, .t2').removeClass('active');
}, 3500);
```

Comment: What is the goal of your code? What is it supposed to do?

Comment: why dont you use setInterval instead setTimeout if your goal is to toggle the active class in certain interval??

Comment: just a quality of life and to delay a few animations so it looks seemless

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since all the classes and timeouts follow simple patterns, you can use a loop.

```
for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $(`.b${1+i}, .t${5-i}`).addClass("active");
    }, 3000 + i*100);
    setTimeout(function() {
        $(`.b${1+i}, .t${5-i}`).removeClass("active");
    }, 3200 + i*100);
}
```

Comment: Im actually new to javascript and loops kinda scare me when i see them, but I understood this one right away. It also worked! thank you for this.

Comment: this code works in VScode, but when I run it on netbeans the variable "i" is not recognized within the setTimeout function

Comment: That makes no sense, it's declared in `for (let i = 0; ....)`. It might be using a transpiler for older versions of JavaScript, and it has a bug.

Comment: actually netbeans wasnt supporting typescript so i had to do a workaround by putting a backslash  $(`.b\${1+i}, .t\${5-i}`).removeClass("active");

Comment: This is JavaScript, not TypeScript. It uses ES6 template literals.

Answer (score 0):

You could use arrow functions to reduce the statements to one line each:

```js
window.setTimeout(() => $(".b1, .t5").addClass("active"),    3000);
window.setTimeout(() => $(".b1, .t5").removeClass("active"), 3200);
window.setTimeout(() => $(".b2, .t4").addClass("active"),    3100);
window.setTimeout(() => $(".b2, .t4").removeClass("active"), 3300);
window.setTimeout(() => $(".b3, .t3").addClass("active"),    3200);
window.setTimeout(() => $(".b3, .t3").removeClass("active"), 3400);
window.setTimeout(() => $(".b4, .t2").addClass("active"),    3300);
window.setTimeout(() => $(".b4, .t2").removeClass("active"), 3500);
```

But since this seams like a repeatable algorithm you can use for loops:

```
for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    const element = $(`.b${i + 1}, .t${5 - i}`);
    window.setTimeout(() => element.addClass('active'),    3000 + i * 100);
    window.setTimeout(() => element.removeClass('active'), 3200 + i * 100);
}
```

Comment: its almost the same as Barmar's answer and it works as well. Its nice having more than one way to do things, I learned new things today thank you!

Comment: Yeah, we posted it almost at the same time, I wouldn't have posted it if I had seen his answer

Comment: But mark @Barmar 's answer as the answer please, so that other people know your problem is solved

Answer (score 0):

How about this,

```
const actions = [
    { class: ".b1, .t5", classParam: "active", addTimeout: 3000, removeTimeout:3200 },
    { class: ".b2, .t4", classParam: "active", addTimeout: 3100, removeTimeout:3100 },
    { class: ".b3, .t3", classParam: "active", addTimeout: 3200, removeTimeout:3400 },
    { class: ".b4, .t2", classParam: "active", addTimeout: 3300, removeTimeout:3500 },
];

for (let i = 0; i < actions.length; i++) {
    let el = actions[i];
    window.setTimeout(function () {
        $(el.class).addClass(el.classParam);
    }, el.addTimeout);
    window.setTimeout(function () {
        $(el.class).addClass(el.classParam);
    }, el.removeTimeout);
}
```

Do let me know what you think about it. Classes could be different in the future and might not follow a pattern.

Comment: I was aiming for a shorter code like Barmar's and MrCodingB's answers, but this also works actually, thank you!